# Eclipse RCP - limit help view to a single perspective

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In my RCP application when I open Help view using `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().displayContext()` method it appears in all perspectives, not only the currently active. Is it possible to limit it only to the current perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any support for this in the help system.

You could perhaps install an `IPerspectiveListener` (or `IPerspectiveListener4`) on the workbench page to listen for the changes to the perspective and manually close the help (the help is in a view called `org.eclipse.help.ui.HelpView`).

Comment: Sadly, I think this the only answer that does not include modifying code or manifest in org.eclipse.ui.help or at least messing with internal packages, but it is far from perfect.